# Cakephp Model association with user id

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I have the following model in Cakephp:

```
class Post extends AppModel {

var $name = 'Post';

var $belongsTo = array(             
        "User" => array(
                 'className' => 'User',
                 'foreignKey' => 'user',
                 'fields'=>array('id', 'username', 'last_action', 'type', 'status', 'country')
                  ), 
);
var $hasOne = array(             
            "Follower" => array(
                  'className' => 'Follower',
                  'foreignKey' => false,
                  'fields'=>'target',
                  'conditions' => array('Follower.target = Post.user', 'Follower.user = 21')
              ), 
);
}
```

This model gets the posts from the database and includes the basic user information. My goal is to include in the same query if the user who is retrieving the data is following or not whoever created that post.

For this reason I am trying to associate the table followers. But in order to get the appropriate result I should submit the user id, (in this case 21). The problem is that I don't know how to pass the logged user ID variable.

Does anybody know how to do it or how this model should be written?
Thanks

Comment: Describe the structure of the Follower model and how any of its fields are used to relate to another model. My guess is that this relationship is not part of the Post model but somehow part of the User model.

Comment: Why hard code the user id in the conditions? This will skew the result for all queries. the conditions should be part of the query that you build for results,

Comment: Follower table has only 2 fields, user (the follower) and target (who is followed). If I do the relationship in the User, I run in the same problem, of the user Id.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $hasOne code within the Post model. Immediately before executing your `find`, use the [bindModel](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly)

For example, this would be called from a method within the Post model (changing the 21 to your logged in user's id) prior to the `find`:

```
$this->bindModel(
         array('hasOne'=>array(
                  'Follower' => array(
                    'className' => 'Follower',
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'fields'=>'target',
                    'conditions' => array(
                      'Follower.target' => 'Post.user', 
                      'Follower.user' => '21')
                   )
          ))
        );
```